# All CSV values in column 0 are strings

Tags: python-2.7, csv

For some reason a csv file I wrote (win7) with Python has all the values as a string in column 0 and cannot perform any operation.

It has no labels.

The format is (I would like to keep the last value - date - as a date format):

```
"Rob,Avanti,Ave,12.83,Max,4.0,Min,-21.9,analist disp:,-1.0,"" date: Feb 04, 2016            """
```

EDIT - When I read it with the csv module it prints it out like:

```
['Rob,Avanti,Ave,12.83,Max,4.0,Min,-21.9,analist disp:,-1.0," date: Feb 04, 2016\t\t\t"']
```

What is the best way to convert the strings into comma separated values like this?

```
Rob,Avanti,Ave,12.83,Max,4.0,Min,-21.9,analist disp:,-1.0, date:, Feb 04, 2016
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you looking to write the data correctly in the first place, or read the file you have now and write out a corrected one?

Comment: @DSM the ideal is to write the data correctly in the first place (I already had great difficulty in doing so), but I am happy to be able read what I have now and to write a new file with the data properly structured. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
s="Rob,Avanti,Ave,12.83,Max,4.0,Min,-21.9,analist disp:,-1.0,"" date: Feb 04, 2016      """

print(s)
Rob,Avanti,Ave,12.83,Max,4.0,Min,-21.9,analist disp:,-1.0, date: Feb 04, 2016
```

to add a comma after "date:" you need to add some logic (like replace ":" with ":,"; or after first word etc.

Comment: I don't think a simple `print` is the solution here

Answer (score 0):

First, your date field is quoted, which is ok (and needed) because there is a comma inside:

```
" date: Feb 04, 2016            "
```

But then the whole line also gets quoted (and thus seen as a single field). And because there are already quotes around the date field, those get escaped with another quote:

```
"Rob,Avanti,Ave,12.83,Max,4.0,Min,-21.9,analist disp:,-1.0,"" date: Feb 04, 2016          """
```

So, if you remove that last quoting, everything should be fine (but you might want to trim the date field):

```
Rob,Avanti,Ave,12.83,Max,4.0,Min,-21.9,analist disp:,-1.0," date: Feb 04, 2016            "
```

If you want it exactly like this, you need another comma after `date:` :

```
Rob,Avanti,Ave,12.83,Max,4.0,Min,-21.9,analist disp:,-1.0, date:,"Feb 04, 2016"
```

On the other hand, it would be better to use a header instead:

```
Name,Name2,Ave,Max,Min,analist disp,date
Rob,Avanti,12.83,4.0,-21.9,-1.0,"Feb 04, 2016"
```